# How do I delete lines without "." in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

In Notepad++, I have many lines in the format:

```
abc.xyz
```

where "abc" might have space or - or numbers.

How do I delete lines without "."? So if a line does not have any ".", I want it removed completely, not even leave an empty line.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### How to delete lines without `.`?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^[^\.]*\r\n`

  - You can replace `\r\n` with different EOL (End of Line) regular expressions depending on the EOLs in your file (see "I have a different EOL in my file, what can I do?" and "I don't care what EOLs my file uses, what can I do?" below).
- Clear "Replace with"
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Notes:

- The above assumes that the last line in the file has a trailing EOL.
- The above also assumes you are editing a text file with Windows EOLs, `\r\n`.

**Before**:

```
abc.xyz
abcdef
abc 123.xyz
abc 123def
```

**After**:

```
abc.xyz
abc 123.xyz
```

---

#### I have a different EOL in my file, what can I do?

- The Windows EOL is `\r\n`.
- If you are using files with a different EOL you can convert them to Windows EOLs using Menu "Edit" > "EOL Conversion".
- If you aren't working with Windows EOLs, and you don't wish to convert them, use the following instead:

  - Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs
  - Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

---

#### I don't know or care what EOLs my file uses, what can I do?

- You can use `\R` or `(?:\r\n?|\n)` or `(?:\r?\n?)` instead of `\r\n`. This gets around any issue with the EOLs actually used in the file.
- You can also use `(?:\r?\n?|$)`. This expression will work if there is no EOL in the last line of the file.

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: You can use \R to match any linebreak.

Comment: @user694733 Please explain? `\r` does not match the EOL on Windows. If you remove the `\n` you are left with blank lines. OP Stated "I want it removed completely, not even leave an empty line."

Comment: Uppercase R. N++ uses PCRE which has this as a special character class if my memory serves me right.

Comment: @user694733 Ah. OK. Tested it and it works.

Comment: http://regex101.com is a better site for learning regex than regexexr

Comment: @cat Thanks. I'll add that link to the answer and my Notepad++ regexp answer template ;)

Comment: If you have PCRE, you might as well just use a negative lookahead assertion.  That's much easier to read.

Comment: You can solve the newline problem on this way: `(?:\r\n?|\n)` or `(?:\r?\n?)`. Both should work. Notepad++ RegExp engine is quite good, and should work fine with those options.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nice. Added to answer.

Comment: Why not just use $ for the end of the line?  That seems to simplify your answer quite a bit.  I'm genuinely asking...  I want to know if there's a problem with $...

Comment: @JPhi1618 Because it doesn't work. `$` doesn't match the EOL characters so using a `$` leaves blank lines. OP said "I want it removed completely, not even leave an empty line."

Comment: @JPhi1618 That won't work, but `(?:\r?\n?|$)` works. And it is great for extra portability.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Ah. `(?:\r?\n?|$)` will work if there is no EOL on the last line of the file, right?

Comment: Exactly. That is the entire idea. But I don't know if the O.P. wants it or not...

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is correct, but you won't always have regex at ready. So I present a simpler solution.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> – click on tab Mark
2. Set "Find what" to `.`
3. Check option "Bookmark line" (courtesy of Wrass)
4. Search mode = Normal
5. Click Mark All -> You should see a blue circle next to the bookmarked line numbers.
6. Then navigate to menu Search -> Bookmark -> Remove Unmarked Lines.

Comment: This is a nice simple alternative, however you may want to mention that you should also check the 'Bookmark line' option in the Mark dialog.  Failure to do so will result in **all** lines being removed.

Comment: Good point, my notepad remembered it from the last time, so I forgot about that.

Comment: I use regex all the time, but I would still use this method for its simplicity.  Disclaimer: I also use the various bookmark functions in Notepad++ a lot.

Comment: Since you were unhappy with your formatting, I've submitted an edit that I think you'll find more pleasant. Feel free to reject it or roll back if you disagree.